# Is the use of the <form> tag necessary in ReactJS that have HOC input tags that handle form-esque events and behaviour?

Tags: reactjs

The use of the form tag seems redundant especially in SPAs where the default action of refreshing the page is more of a hindrance than a feature: *why include a tag only to have to write `e.preventDefault()` to prevent its default behaviour every time it is used*?

Any form behaviour can be handled with a combination input tags, local component/application state and methods.

Form submission can be handled from handlers on inputs/controlled inputs themselves that in turn call some central form submission method.

I have tried this when creating a dynamic form component (inputs and types are built from an object dynamically) with no obvious downsides.

> My question is: Given a situation where **input tags are configured as HOCs** whose events such as onChange, onClick and onKeydown handle the majority of events (like form submit's event like submit when the enter key is pressed) ***and*** whose value is controlled by state: 
>   Are there any reasons as to why omitting the use of
>   form tags to build a form within ReactJS is a bad idea?

Comment: Would be a duplicate if it wasn't for the fact that within React we effectively spoof behaviours with the Virtual DOM and Synthetic events. If I'm controlled components for inputs allow for the use of dynamically assigned validation per input type _and_ include any existing behaviours from form, the form tag feels redundant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a `<form>` tag gives you automatic form behavior, like form submission when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when an input has focus. There is zero benefit from avoiding a form tag.

Comment: onEnter could be added by creating a HOC of inputs which is what I've done to manage input state and events. In this case, would a form tag be needed?

Comment: Why would you poorly and manually re-create behavior you get for free?

Comment: What makes defining your own Key event handler in a wrapper of a controlled input "poor"? That same key handler would also handle validation in one go without having to write it all in a single onSubmit.

Comment: Read the dupe question answer. You don't get default behavior like mobile safari's "go" button and i'm sure other things.

Comment: Cool, had a full read of that question.  Cheers for taking the time to answer as well

Comment: I mean it is 2 more lines of code to write

Comment: @Sirhennihau Pay attention to what's already been said. you need to check for enter in each form field, you need to check for onclick of the submit button, you have to manually configure disabling the form (instead of disabling the submit button which works out of the box), you don't get document.forms, you don't get form.reset(), and probably lots of other things I don't know about, and you don't get the benefit of browser APIs evolving around forms.

Comment: Chrome complains if no form tag is used with a password field. But do I ABSOLUTELY NEED a form tag, or is it a formality? What about accessibility concerns? Is a form tag necessary to pass W3C validation?

Comment: @John you are welcome to try testing your button/input whatever without a wrapping `<form>` tag on every modern browser on every possible device, and then test it with screen readers on those devices, and password managers, and any other software that works with browser forms (like text expanders), and you can verify if it does what you need. Or you can just use a form tag. You don't NEED `<html>` / `<body>` / `<head>` tags either, some browsers will figure out what you mean.

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay - I regularly forgo the form element. An input field shouldn’t NEED a form tag imo but i can see where other things may rely on that. I suppose this answers my questions, it’s quite logical when you consider HTML as a standard- of course inputs would be in a form tag. But a form tag provides default behaviors that I often don’t want, like a submit behavior. Sure that can be handled with preventDefault but why go the extra mile when you can just skip the form tag? Idk that a standard exists which states all forms must be in a form tag, is there?